# PostgreSQL errors after switching dev machines (Rails development)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am currently developing a Rails app which uses PostgreSQL in both development and production. I began development on my laptop but now I want to begin development on a new desktop (both use Ubuntu as the OS). I committed all changes on the laptop, git cloned on the desktop, installed the required gems, installed PostgreSQL, and did a rake db:create and migrate. However, I'm still getting database errors that I do not see when I run the app on my laptop.

For example:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#show
PG::Error: ERROR:  column works.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "works".* FROM "works"  WHERE "works"."user_id" = 1
                                             ^
: SELECT "works".* FROM "works"  WHERE "works"."user_id" = 1
```

It seems as if the SQL syntax contains added quotes that do not belong there. Again, this error does not occur on my laptop.

The database.yml file is setup correctly:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  username: bruce
```

I never developed the app using sqlite so I'm not sure why I'm getting these strange errors. Did I miss a step when I git cloned my repo on my new dev machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL tells you he misses a user_id column, so you must launch `rake db:migrate`

Check your two `db/schema.rb` in your environment. Open a console on your first environment and ensure that the works table has a user_id attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! For some reason the user_id column in my second environment was named users_id (plural). It might have been caused by a mistake I made earlier on in development and it was carried over with the migration. I renamed the column to user_id and everything worked ok!